# Android, trying to figure out how to chnage the package name

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a copy of my android project within eclipse.  I used ctr c and ctr v, which worked.  But, is their a way to change the package name? Cannot figure out how to do it.  I did see a message saying you can use the refactor.  I did not see a option for this in the refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name of the application when it's built comes from the AndroidManifest.xml

Just change the package attribute of the root element:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.yourdomain.newpackage"
          android:versionCode="28"
          android:versionName="2.2.1"
          android:installLocation="auto">
```

To change the package name of all the classes, select the root element in your project hierarchy, right-click and select Refactor > Rename